# Who are other spies that surveyed the land in Numbers 14?

Tags: history, numbers

“And Joshua the son of Nun, and Caleb the son of Jephunneh, *which were* of them that searched the land, rent their clothes:” ‭‭Numbers‬ ‭14‬:‭6‬ ‭KJV‬‬.

Numbers 13:4-16 only speaks on Caleb going, but Joshua is listed in Numbers 14:6 as having gone out to spy as well.

Is there other documentation of others going besides the original listed in Num 13:4-16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taken from Numbers 13:3-16

> <sup>**3**</sup> So at the consent of the LORD, Moses sent them out from the Wilderness of Paran. All the men were leaders of the Israelites, <sup>**4**</sup>
> and these were their names:
>
> From the tribe of Reuben, Shammua son of Zaccur;
>
> <sup>**5**</sup> from the tribe of Simeon, Shaphat son of Hori;
>
> <sup>**6**</sup> from the tribe of Judah, **Caleb** son of Jephunneh;
>
> <sup>**7**</sup> from the tribe of Issachar, Igal son of Joseph;
>
> <sup>**8**</sup> from the tribe of Ephraim, **Hoshea** son of Nun;
>
> <sup>**9**</sup> from the tribe of Benjamin, Palti son of Raphu;
>
> <sup>**10**</sup> from the tribe of Zebulun, Gaddiel son of Sodi;
>
> <sup>**11**</sup> from the tribe of Manasseh (a tribe of Joseph), Gaddi son of Susi;
>
> <sup>**12**</sup> from the tribe of Dan, Ammiel son of Gemalli;
>
> <sup>**13**</sup> from the tribe of Asher, Sethur son of Michael;
>
> <sup>**14**</sup> from the tribe of Naphtali, Nahbi son of Vophsi;
>
> <sup>**15**</sup> and from the tribe of Gad, Geuel son of Machi.
>
> <sup>**16**</sup> These were the names of the men Moses sent to spy out the land; and Moses gave to Hoshea son of Nun the name Joshua.

Note that "Hoshea" is another name for "Joshua" - in Hebrew, they are almost the same thing.